# Android Tablets resolution and density support

Tags: android-layout, android

Hello Everyone.........

I am working on android tablets that supports 1280x800 and 1024x600 resolution.
What is the best approach for UI design to use dip or px for layout designing. My problem is I want to support all Android Tablets in market with both of these resolutions but there LCD density may vary between 160 to 240 dpi.

- What to do in this situation?
- Android tablets have 240 dpi density or 160 dpi density or may have both?
- Please tell which tablets devices have which density support?
- Is it possible to workon both densities with same screen resolution through same xml layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For layout designing dip is definitely the best approach because you have density independence :

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

As far as I know, since dpi is dots per inch if you have one resolution you should only have  one density.

For calculating easily density see :

http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices#Tablet_computers

Comment: I would like to know, If I have same resolution with different densities then what to do in that situation. Is it possible to work on both densities through my same xml file.

Comment: I work with a 7" tablet 800*480 (scale =1.0) and a 4" 800*480 smartphone (scale =1.5), so same resolution different densities. In order to support the density difference I use dpi which allows me to use only one xml file.

Comment: What name did you gave to layout folder in res

Comment: So I run some tests. If I am under API lvl 13, for tablet 7" I create layout-large and for smartphone layout-small. In both folders I put my main.xml but in the layout-small I divide every fixed size by 1.5 (because it is the scale value for this screen). If I am API lvl 13 I call the two folders respectively large and small : layout-sw600dp and  layout-sw320dp. If you do this programmatically you can retrive scale with : scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

Comment: That means you created two different folders for different densities. But I want to ask is it possible to use same xml for both densities.

Comment: I don t think so, never managed. Sorry. If you create your layout programmatically you just have to write it once, including the scale factor of course.

Answer (score 4):

yes make sure, we make a single layout thate work for all screen or tabs in any density.
Android provide multiple support screen features.

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
        android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>
```

and also putup all imeges in

1. hdpi folder
2. mdpi folder
3. ldpi folder

Answer (score 0):

I have just written a blog post to solve your problem: http://onemanmobile.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-scale-your-android-layouts-to.html

This will give you a tool so you only have to define your layout xml-files for a single density bucket (small/normal/large/xlarge) and have it scale proportionally for tablets and small devices.